# Dropzone with draggable area and input in different locations

Tags: javascript, dropzone.js, dropzone

I'm trying to use Dropzone in my application to enable drag and drop upload. The problem is: I can't upload the file at the time I select a file, I need to wait the user click on 'Submit' on entire form (I don't have a form only to file upload) to upload my file.
And I have another problem, the draggable area (my div) is not in the same place as my input (where I need my uploaded file).

It's something like this:

```
<form ...>
  <input type="file"/>
</form>
<div id="myDivWhereUserWillDropTheFile">
</div>
```

Is that possible to solve with Dropzone?

Answer (score 0):

It depends on the exact flow you want to achieve, but to disable autoupload take a took at `autoProcessQueue` and `autoQueue` options.

http://www.dropzonejs.com/#config-autoProcessQueue

From there you can use a `addedfile` event handler to programmatically set your input

http://www.dropzonejs.com/#event-addedfile